# Add class to elements based on matching field from select value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently working on a client project where I have a list of properties. Like this:

```
<div class="property">
<h2>Property Name</h2>
<span>￼0 – 1,500 sq ft</span>
</div>
```

Each property has a 'space available (sq ft)'. I also have a select box containing all the available space options like this:

```
<select id="selectList" name="field_53c53945dcb87">
    <option value="1500">￼0 – 1,500 sq ft</option>
    <option value="3000">￼1,500 – 3,000 sq ft</option>
    <option value="5000">3,000 – 5,000 sq ft</option>
    <option value="10000">5,000 – 10,000 sq ft</option>
    <option value="20000">10,000 – 20,000 sq ft</option>
</select>
```

I would like to add a class of 'selected' to all of the properties that have the currently selected value. My jQuery so far is:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Create a variable with current selected item
        var currentSelection = $('#selectList :selected').val();
        // Find all elements containing variable
        // Add class to all elements containing variable
        $('div:contains('" + currentSelection + "')').addClass('selected');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas why this is currently not adding the class to the divs with the selected value?

Thanks in advance,
Marc

---

#### Update

@billyonecan's JS Fiddle here shows the answer I was looking for. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/DMFLY/3

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle to try help your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/9ttm7/

Comment: Your option values don't match the text in your div, however, the option text does, so use that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/DMFLY/3/

Comment: ... this has nothing do to with your question, but do remember to remove the "selected" class at some point! :)

Comment: Thanks Billyonecan. Your solution worked for me. Top stuff. Can I up vote this answer? 

@EsbenBoye-Jacobsen That's a good point. How would I remove it when another choice is picked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you have your quotes the wrong way around when trying to concatenate the `currentSelection` variable:

```
$('div:contains("' + currentSelection + '")').addClass('selected');
```

The second is that the selected option's value does match match up with the text in the div, so the above selector will never return an element. As your code is currently, you could use the selected option's text:

```
var currentSelection = $('#selectList option:selected').text();
```

As for removing the class when another option is selected, just attach a `change` handler to the select, and let that do the work for you:

```
$('#selectList').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); 

    $('.property').removeClass('selected')
                  .filter(':contains("' + selected + '")').addClass('selected');
}).change();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMFLY/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, your div does not contain the value. You're looking for at the value "1500" when your value in fact is "1,500" - My suggestion would be to adopt one of the values to match the other :)

http://jsfiddle.net/PDE8t/ - Updated version with code like this...

```
 <select id="selectList" name="field_53c53945dcb87">
      <option value="1,500">￼0 – 1,500 sq ft</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Esben, 

Thanks for this. I can actually change the value on the property span to be the value from the select option. How would that change my jQuery after? 

So I could have this: 

<div class="property">
<h2>Property Name</h2>
<span>1500</span>
</div>

Comment: Ah! I have solved this using @Billyonecan's message above and yours too. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, one more point on this. What if I wanted to add a class to all of the properties that don't match at the same time? 

So:

If a property matches, give it a class of selected
If a property doesn't match, give it a class of unselected?

Comment: Have a look at `.not()` in the jQuery API -  http://api.jquery.com/not/ - With that you'll be able to select all the divs that does not have the `selected` class. Fiddle with a small example of the `.not()`: http://jsfiddle.net/LWKHN/

Comment: Cheers Esben. That's handy to know.

Comment: No problem - If you ever find yourself not knowing what to do someday, look through the api... There's really some nifty stuff in there!