# Remove class from 'all' filter on Select

Tags: jquery, html, select

Yesterday, I was working on this question: [Add class to elements based on matching field from select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780114/add-class-to-elements-based-on-matching-field-from-select-value)

Today, I've run into an additional problem.

As it stands, I have a select of options:

```
<select id="selectList" name="field_53c53945dcb87">
<option value="1500">￼0 – 1,500 sq ft</option>
<option value="3000">￼1,500 – 3,000 sq ft</option>
<option value="5000">3,000 – 5,000 sq ft</option>
<option value="10000">5,000 – 10,000 sq ft</option>
<option value="20000">10,000 – 20,000 sq ft</option></select>
```

I also have a list of properties that are something like this:

```
<div class="property">
<h2>Name of Property</h2>
<a href="#" class="button">More Details</a>
</div>
```

My jQuery adds a class of active_select to a property which has the value of the select and a class of dormant_select to a property which does not.

The problem is that I would like an 'All' option which removes both the active_ and dormant_select classes from all properties. This is the default option – the default state is a little different to the active_select which is why I can't just make the active_select the default. Here's what I have tried but it does not quite work because it treats the 'All' as if it should have dormant_select on it:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Add an all function to default when page loads
        $("#selectList").prepend("<option value='all' selected class='selectAll'>ALL</option>");
        // If is 'All', remove all dormant/active select classes
        $("#selectList").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('selectAll')){
                    $('.property').removeClass('active_select dormant_select');
                }
                else {

                }
            });
        }).change();    
        // Create a variable with current selected item
        $('#selectList').on('change', function() {
            // Set selected option into variable
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); 
            // Remove active_select 
            // Filter through DOM to compare select with content of divs with class of property
            // If .property has match against select, add class active_select
            $('.property').removeClass('active_select').filter(':contains("' + selected + '")').addClass('active_select');
//This is where the extra dormant_select gets added to the 'all' option erroneously
            $('.property').removeClass('dormant_select').filter(':not(:contains('+ selected +'))').addClass('dormant_select');
}).change();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas how I could remove dormant_select and active_select from all elements when a user selects 'all' from the drop down?

---

#### Update + Solution

Thanks to Koala_dev, I got the solution with a tiny couple of changes:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Add an all function to default when page loads
        $("#selectList").prepend("<option value='all' selected>ALL</option>");
        $('#selectList').on('change', function () {
    // Set selected option into variable
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

    if (selected == "ALL") {
        $('.property').removeClass('active_select dormant_select');
        return;
    }

    $('.property').filter(':contains("' + selected + '")').addClass('active_select').removeClass('dormant_select');
    $('.property').filter(':not(:contains(' + selected + '))').addClass('dormant_select').removeClass('active_select');
}).change();

    });


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a check to see if `"All"` was selected and remove the classes:

```
$('#selectList').on('change', function () {
    // Set selected option into variable
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

    if (selected == "All") {
        $('.property').removeClass('active_select dormant_select');
        return;
    }

    $('.property').removeClass('active_select').filter(':contains("' + selected + '")').addClass('active_select');
    $('.property').removeClass('dormant_select').filter(':not(:contains(' + selected + '))').addClass('dormant_select')
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to rearrange a couple of the removeClass statements to make sure everything went how it should but thanks so much.